# OpenCV won't work with Eclipse CDT on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to setup OpenCV with Eclipse CDT on ubuntu. I have followed the steps given on the OpenCV website(http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html) and am using their sample programme.

The pkg-config commands shows that I have openCV installed in the same location but even after linking it with the project after following the steps, the header files have a question mark on Eclipse and all subsequent lines are marked as problems. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You may provide the include paths for OpenCV in the Eclipse Project Settings, check `C++ General -> Paths & Symbols`.